# Undefined Variable & String Conversion Exception

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I was trying to use the `Blade` template engine and got this errors

**My Controller**

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController
{ 
    protected $layout = 'home';

    public function index()
    {        
        $data = array(
            'heading' => 'Hello Laravel (from Home)',
            'body' => 'This is awesome, from the HomeController'
        );

        $this->layout->content = View::make('home',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

**View - [Try 1]**

```
...
    @section('message')
        {{$data}}
    @stop
```

**ERROR**

```
ErrorException
Array to string conversion
```

**View - [Try 2]**

```
....
    @section('message')
        <?php print_r($data); ?>
    @stop
```

**ERROR**

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you're defining the layout and the view.

You're defining the layout of the controller as 'home' and then rendering the view 'home' as the content of the layout, which basically means you're rendering the same file again as the content. You should have a separate file for the layout. You could have `View::make('index', $data)` and make a file called index.blade.php. See [here](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating) for more information

Comment: I suspect there is another issue with how you define the layouts. You're defining the layout of the controller as 'home' and then rendering the view 'home' as the content of the layout, which basically means you're rendering the same file again as the content. You should have a separate file for the layout. You could have `View::make('index', $data)` and make a file called index.blade.php. See [here](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating) for more information

Comment: Thanks. That actually was the problem. I have a home file under layouts folder and one outside. Now it works like butter... Thank You @

Comment: I have rewritten this answer appropriately.